# Handeling Node, Express background errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am quite unsure how I should properly handle uncaught exceptions that occurs in my node.js/express app. Right now I have an Express app that will send all caught errors to an Express error handeler `using next(err)`:

```
function(err, req, res, next) {
   // Do something with the error
}
```

This seems to work all fine and well for errors I have `anticipated`. For instance a database connection not working, essentially all things that will return a `callback(err)`. Thought problem occurs when I want to preform a background task, which will finish after the response has been sent. For instance:

```
app.get('/url', function(req, res) {
   BackgroundTask.run() // Here an uncaught exception occurs, for instance a bug
   res.send('Running your background task')
}
```

The background modules that I want to run aren't express *related* (no use of req,res) and upon a caught errors they will use a custom in errorHandeler that will send the error to some error reporting service. However when an uncaught exception occurs in one of these background tasks I have no clue how to send the error to my error report service (Raygun in this case). The only thing that seems to work is to add a `process.on('uncaughtException')` event listener. However almost every post on the subject describes the latter a 'bad' or crude way of doing things. They seems to recommand using node `domains` however I don't really see how I can implement these for background tasks.

Comment: Why not try and find out which errors you're not yet catching, and add proper error handling for those? Also, what exactly is stopping you from sending an error report to an external service from the `uncaughtException` handler?

Comment: This is my own question which was just to broad. The information is out of date and its a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I use `process.on(uncaughtException)`, because all you're really trying to do is catch the output from the error and shut the server down gracefully (and then restart).  I don't see any reason to do anything more complicated than that, because by nature of the exception, you don't want your application doing anything else in that state *other* than shutting down.

Domains *are* an alternative way of dealing with this, but it's not necessarily better than using the process handler, because you're effectively writing custom logic to handle things that you aren't anticipating.  It does give you finer granularity in terms of *what* your error handler does for different error types, but ultimately you're still potentially running your application in an unknown state after handling it.  I'd rather have my application log the exception, shut down, and then i'll fix the error so it never happens again, rather than risking my user's data on a domain solution which may or may not have handled the error correctly, depending on the nuance of the error it encountered.

Comment: FWIW, domains are likely to be [phased out](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/66).